# Rationalisable strategies

Tags: game-theory

Consider a two-player game with the following strategy spaces: S1 = [0, 5] and S2 = [0, 5]. Suppose the players’ best-response functions, s1 = BR1(s2) and s2 = BR2(s1), are as pictured here. What is the set of rationalizable strategy profiles for this game?

[image: Best response functions]

Answer (score 0):

The process to compute the rationalizable sets for the two players is iteratively computing *k-rationaliable sets* let's denote them with $S_1^k$ and $S_2^k$ for the two players respectively. The full set of strategies are the 0-rationalizable sets, i.e. $S_1^0 = S_1$ and $S_2^0 = S_2$ the update formulas are:

$$
S_1^{k+1} = BR_1(S_2^k) \\
S_2^{k+1} = BR_2(S_1^k)
$$

As an example in the 1st iteration you will get something like
$$
S_1^1 = BR1(S_2^0) = BR1([0;5]) = [1;4] \\
S_2^1 = BR2(S_1^0) = BR2([0;5]) = [0;4]
$$

The interpretation is that it can not be rational for player 1 to play anything outside [1;4] and for player 2 to play anything outside [0;4].

In the second iteration you will get (by visual inspection of the graphs):
$$
S_1^2 = BR1(S_2^1) = BR1([0;4]) = [1;3.5] \\
S_2^2 = BR2(S_1^1) = BR2([1;4]) = [0.6;3.2]
$$

The interpretation is that knowing that it can not be rational for player 2 to play anything outside [0;4] it can not be rational for player 1 to play anything outside [1, 3.5]. And knowing that it can not be rational for player 1 to play anything outside [1;4] it can not be rational for player 2 to play anything outside [0.6;3.2].

Iterating further the sets will converge to:
$$
S_1^\infty = [2;3] \\
S_2^\infty = [1;3]
$$
which are the rationalizable strategies for the two players.